# Peripheral not connecting to iOS

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez, bluetooth-peripheral

I'm attempting to connect a bluez peripheral to an iOS device; it's not working.

Please find below logs on peripheral side. I'm advertising using `hciconfig hci0 leadv` but I don't see any "Connect" option on Scanner applications on phone. Also `bluez-4.101` doesn't have `hciconfig hci0 leadv`**`0`** option to make it connectable.

With the same device acting as a Central I am able to make LE connections with other BLE devices, so that confirms kernel LE support and device is fine, only some bluez issues I assume are there.

```
> HCI Event: LE Meta Event (0x3e) plen 19
    LE Connection Complete
      status 0x00 handle 1025, role slave
      bdaddr 67:5D:F6:87:3D:2C (Random)
> ACL data: handle 1025 flags 0x02 dlen 7
    ATT: MTU req (0x02)
      client rx mtu 158
 > ACL data: handle 1025 flags 0x02 dlen 27
 > ACL data: handle 1025 flags 0x01 dlen 27
 > ACL data: handle 1025 flags 0x01 dlen 9
    L2CAP(d): cid 0x003a len 59 [psm 0]
      0000: .9......com.appl
      0010: e.BT.TS."....com
      0020: .apple.BTLEServe
      0030:                 r.classic..
> ACL data: handle 1025 flags 0x02 dlen 11
    L2CAP(d): cid 0x003a len 7 [psm 0]
      0000:                              ......
> HCI Event: Disconn Complete (0x05) plen 4
    status 0x00 handle 1025 reason 0x13
    Reason: Remote User Terminated Connection
```

How can I get this peripheral to connect?

Comment: bluez-4.101 is **highly** outdated and almost certainly the cause of all your issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading to the [latest BlueZ version](http://www.bluez.org/download/) will solve the GATT related issues.

Quote from the linked page:

> The 2.x , 3.x  and 4.x series of libraries and packages are deprecated and not supported anymore by BlueZ developers. If you are using them please update to the 5.x series. The download link is only provided for reference.

Comment: Thanks Zimano for the reply, but I am using kernel 2.6.37 and as per bluez.org Bluez-5.x supports only kernel-3.5.x onwards.

Comment: Is there any way that i can use bluez-5.x with my kernel 2.6.37 ?

Comment: I understand, but I don't think that is possible. You would usually need to upgrade your kernel. :(

Comment: Thanks Zimano, there are so many other interfaces dependency and i doubt if i can upgrade the kernel.

Comment: Hi Zimano,

I tried bluez 5.30 on kernel 3.13 and found out there is no improvement on connection issue with iOS Central/peripheral. I still get Remote user termiated connection ? Can you please suggest now ?

Comment: Make a separate question about it, and I'll try and answer it. Be as specific and informative as possible! :)